# How to checked checkbox main when sub checkbox not checked?

Tags: javascript, jquery, checkbox

How to checked checkbox main when sub checkbox not checked ?

When checkbox `id="checkItem1"` and `id="checkItem2"` and `id="checkItem3"` not checked,

i want to auto checked checkbox `id="checkAll"` how can i do that ?

http://jsfiddle.net/peap/sydzL8Lc/11/

```
<input type="checkbox" id="checkAll" checked > Check All
<hr />
<input type="checkbox" id="checkItem1"> Item 1
<input type="checkbox" id="checkItem2"> Item 2 
<input type="checkbox" id="checkItem3"> Item3
```

Comment: How much wood could a woodchuck chuck...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can do it like bellow

```
$('input[id^="checkItem"]').change(function(){
    if($('input[id^="checkItem"]:checked').length===0)
        $('#checkAll').prop('checked',true);
})
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/sydzL8Lc/12/)

Comment: can i split id checkbox ?

Comment: @การกรกรกรกกกนรกี Sorry I didn't get you, what do you mean by split id?

Comment: use eg checkItem1 , checkItem2 , checkItem3 in code .

Answer (score 0):

I did a [**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/sydzL8Lc/15/) on the full functionality you will need including including when user click the checkAll all boxes change to checked if checkAll is checked or to not checked otherwise. Also there's a on change listener on each of them to listen if the user check all of them and to change the checkAll to checked and backwards.

**HTML:**

```
<input type="checkbox" id="checkAll"> Check All
    <hr />
    <div class='js-checkboxes'>
    <input type="checkbox" id="checkItem1"> Item 1
    <input type="checkbox" id="checkItem2"> Item 2 
    <input type="checkbox" id="checkItem3"> Item3
    </div>
```

**Javascript:**

```
$('.js-checkboxes > input').on('change', function() {
    var isAllChecked = true;

    $('.js-checkboxes > input').each(function() {
        if (!this.checked) {
            isAllChecked = false;
        }
    });

    if (isAllChecked) {
        $('#checkAll')[0].checked = true;
    } else {
        $('#checkAll')[0].checked = false;
    }
});

$('#checkAll').on('change', function() {
    if (this.checked) {
        $('.js-checkboxes > input').each(function() {
            this.checked = true;
        });
    } else {
        $('.js-checkboxes > input').each(function() {
            this.checked = false;
        });
    }
});
```

Answer (score -1):

```
$("input[id^='checkItem']").change(function(){
   if(!$("#checkItem1").is(":checked") && !$("#checkItem2").is(":checked") && !$("#checkItem3").is(":checked"))
   {
      $("#checkAll").prop("checked",true)
   }
}
```

EDIT :- [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/sydzL8Lc/14/)

Comment: what if user unchecks the `checkAll` checkbox? You would be setting it to checked

Comment: @charlietfl..i just answered as per question i can't give my own opinions during answering.

Comment: it's not an opinion, the event handler shouldn't be bound to all checkboxes on page and make it impossible for user to uncheck something

Comment: @charlietfl...okk fixed that but its not the big issue and i don't think it is the cause of downvoting..

Comment: @balexandre...plzz see updated answer i think that is what you were pointing out..